# Send email in asp.net,html

Tags: html, asp.net

This is my index.aspx form.

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="SendMail.aspx">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name"
        required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number"
        required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"
        required>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
    Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

And this is my SendMail.aspx form.

```
<%
Response.Write("Need : " & Request.Form("whatneed") & "<br>")
Response.Write("Budget : " & Request.Form("budget") & "<br>")
Response.Write("When : " & Request.Form("whenneed") & "<br>")
Response.Write("Location : " & Request.Form("location") & "<br>")
Response.Write("Name : " & Request.Form("name") & "<br>")
Response.Write("Description : " & Request.Form("address") & "<br>")
Response.Write("Mobile No : " & Request.Form("mobile") & "<br>")
Response.Write("Landline No : " & Request.Form("landline") & "<br>")
Response.Write("Email Id : " & Request.Form("email") & "<br>")

MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.To.Add("saravana17.ams@gmail.com");
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("saro17.ams@gmail.com");
mailMessage.Subject = "ASP.NET e-mail test";
mailMessage.Body = "Hello world,\n\nThis is an ASP.NET test e-mail!";
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.feo.co.in");
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
Response.Write("E-mail sent!"); 
%>
```

I don't know why mail is not sending here.Please help me to fix this.

Comment: what you don't know ? did you got any _error_ ?

Comment: Please help me to send email. I got this error when i run this code. BC30451: Name 'MailMessage' is not declared.

Comment: your code seems to be incorrect/insufficient to me. have a look [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-email-using-Gmail-SMTP-Mail-Server-in-ASPNet.aspx) for details explanation

Comment: My index.aspx is fully designed with html tags.Is it possible to fix the code i used here.i'm a starter in ASP.net.

Comment: you need to show that code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that we can check and let you know where is the mistake

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tfkc5L0q/3/   Pasted code in this link

Comment: ok.thanks.Please help me to fix it as soon as possible.Because already i have wasted 2 days with it.

Comment: @coder **_jsFiddle_** for `ASP.NET`?

Comment: @SnazzySanoj: i wanted the html part of the OP, so that I can get a sneak peak of his front end and write the code as per his requirement

Comment: @saravananam: check my answer, try and let me know whether it works or not

Comment: ok. i'm trying your code.

Comment: BC30456: 'btnSubmit_OnClick' is not a member of 'ASP.fairexhibition_test_aspx'. i'm getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your JsFiddle, I found that there are so many silly mistakes in your HTML code.

Here is your `ASP.NET` code:-

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtmobileno" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary pull-right" OnClick="btnSubmit_OnClick" Width="100" Text="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Code behind cs code**

Created a `SendMail()` function which will fire on `buttonclick`

**Note:-** I haven't added validations on the controls, so if you want it you can add as per your requirement.

```
protected void SendMail()
{
    // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
    var fromAddress = "Gmail@gmail.com";
    // any address where the email will be sending
    var toAddress = txtEmail.Text.ToString();
    //Password of your gmail address
    const string fromPassword = "Your gmail password";
    // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
    string subject = txtSubject.Text.ToString();
    // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
    string body = "From: " + txtname.Text + "\n";
    body += "Email: " + txtEmail.Text + "\n";
    // smtp settings
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
    }
    // Passing values to smtp object
    smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
}
```

Now the above function will be called on `Button click` so that every time you enter the details you can call that function.

```
protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    { 
        SendMail(); // Send mail function to send your mail
        txtname.Text = "";
        txtEmail.Text = "";
        txtmobileno.Text = "";
        txtSubject.Text = "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

For a detail explanation have a look at below link:-

**http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/371417/Send-Mail-Contact-Form-using-ASP-NET-and-Csharp**

Comment: @SnazzySanoj: my pleasure, :)

Comment: BC30456: 'btnSubmit_OnClick' is not a member of 'ASP.fairexhibition_sendmail_aspx'. I'm getting this error..

Comment: There is no error in the code which you pasted. The error seems to be coming from another piece of code, you need to either paste the whole code or debug your code step by step.

**NOTE** IS your first line in `aspx` page is properly referenced or not ?? that's the error which it is showing

Comment: I pasted the another piece of code here. https://jsfiddle.net/tfkc5L0q/9/. (Full code)

Comment: I want the first line of the aspx code like :-  `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits=..........` and also the line from `cs` like `public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page` this both should match/properly referenced. Kindly check or show us the code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tfkc5L0q/10/. this is front end. And the server side part is https://dotnetfiddle.net/u8JKE8. Both were updated.And i have pasted the full code

Comment: I guess you are using master page, so do one thing.

**STEPS** 

1)Rename the old page`(SendMail.aspx page)`. 2) Again create the page with the same name by right click  and add the relevant code and check once again. I guess the issue is with the master page reference only.

Comment: Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.... Now this error is coming.

Comment: **If you do New Item in Visual Studio and you select Web Form, it will create a standalone *.aspx web form, which is what you have for your current web form (is this what you did?). You need to select Web Content Form and then select the master page you want attached to it.**

Comment: thanks a lot mr.coder. Finally its working. i got so much of ideas from you. this is the first form i'm working on ASP. i got (learned) many things and ideas from you. you have guided me very well. thanks for your support

Comment: you are welcome, Glad it helped, kindly accept the answer if it helped you :)